# Sftp credentials are stored on my machine - but where?

Tags: gnome, password, gnome-keyring

In the past, I have successfully logged onto a server from my desktop using ftp/sftp. The password was saved somewhere in my system, but I am not sure where. I am now trying to change the password because the password changed on the server, but I am unable to do so.

- I have tried looking for the entry in my Ubuntu keyring. I found an
  entry and deleted it.
- The system still remembered the password when I tried to log on.
- I then deleted ALL entries from my keyring. The system still
  remembered my password.
- I do not have any relevant configuration in .ssh/hosts (in case that
  matters).
- I have tried logging onto the same host using the sftp on the command
  line, using Nautilus, and using Filezilla. In all cases, the system
  does not ask me for a password and I have no idea how to change it.
- I removed references in the folder **/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/** but it
  does not influence anything

Any ideas where I can change this?

Using Ubuntu 18.04, Gnome

Comment: It might be that you're using SSH key authentication instead of passwords to access that server. Does `ssh-add -l` output anything? If you run `ls $HOME/.ssh/id_*`, does it list any SSH key files?

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

If it shows me the list of keys that I use for different projects and accesses to the servers, and these are the ones used to connect, if any of these keys appear, what action should I take?

Comment: @telcoM you were right, apparently it does try to use the ssh keys to connect, I renamed the .ssh folder and it connected successfully, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, I asked you to run `ssh-add -l` and `ls $HOME/.ssh/id_*` and it turned out you have SSH keys set up. You said you have several keys for different projects and accesses: this might be an important detail.

It is likely the stored SFTP credential is actually one of the SSH keys rather than a password.

Alternatively, the remote server administrator may have set a strict limit for number of authentication attempts per single connection attempt, and you have so many keys configured that SSH will burn through all those attempts by trying out various SSH keys before getting to the password prompt, resulting in the remote `sshd` terminating the connection attempt without asking for a password.

(Yes, each key offer counts as one authentication attempt!)

In the comments, you said you already solved it by renaming the `.ssh` directory. As a more user-friendly alternative, you could write a snippet like this into your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host problem.server.hostname
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    # uncomment the line below to offer only a specified key and no other
    # IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_key_file_name_here
    # uncomment the line below to only use password authentication with this host
    # PubkeyAuthentication no
```

This will restrict the keys and/or authentication methods used with a particular host, avoiding the "too many keys" problem.

Comment: Great!, I will also try this solution and I will see what results I will have.